# facebook "register as developer" button is broken

Tags: facebook

"https://developers.facebook.com/onboarding/"
fails on POST in my console and if I manually go to the url

```
Sorry, something went wrong.

We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.
```

Comment: I pinged the people responsible for that page. Thanks for reporting

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and the team at Facebook is working urgently on fixing it - thanks for reporting it. Also, in future, please file these issues at developers.facebook.com/bugs where our oncall team looks at each incoming bug.

[I work at Facebook]